# which solution will be faster on Android?

Tags: java, android

Which solution will be faster on Android 2.1?

1.

```
public void foo(String a, String b)
{
 String msg = a + ": " + b;
 print(msg);
}
```

2.

```
public void foo(String a, String b)
{
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(a.length() + b.length() + 2);
 sb.append(a);
 sb.append(": ");
 sb.append(b);
 print(sb.toString());
}
```

Is android use internally StringBuilder for first solution?

Comment: Easier if we do it for him. That's the Stack Overflow way.  Not "how do I do this" but "you do this".  Until there's some reason to not ask such questions it will continue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In standard Java, the compiler will generate StringBuilder code (under the hood) for String concatenation.  No reason to believe the same is not true of Android, so it probably makes no difference;  go with whichever is more readable to you.

Comment: It's worth adding that the normal java compiler is used to compile java to class files. When the android dex generates the dex file from class files all api usage is already resolved.

Comment: I can confirm that with java 1.6.30, android sdk r16 and adt 16.0.1, string concatenation becomes stringbuilder + append, I've looked in the class and dex.

Comment: I suppose this isn't true if passing the string object around methods

Answer (score 2):

For something that simple, the difference likely will not be noticeable unless you are doing it thousands of times.

It is best to not worry about making small optimizations like these until you have profiled your code and know that this is what is causing it to run slowly.

Answer (score 1):

I think the first is faster in this case since you don't have to initialize the StringBuilder etc..., but you could also measure this.

### BUT:

[Premature optimization is the root of all evil!](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization)

Comment: Agreed, unless it is causing an issue why is the OP even considering optimization here, the code is very trivial and not worth our (or your) time

Answer (score 0):

I am think the first one is faster and easier because you don't have to go through constructing a string builder, and I am pretty sure it would reduce the memory your app needs.

Comment: Probably! Without knowing the specifics of the Java StringBuilder, there is usually a tradeoff where a few concatenations are cheaper than constructing a StringBuilder, but that a StringBuilder pays off if you're doing several.

Answer (score 0):

string is immutable so whenever you manipulate string it creates new string so using + to append strings should use much more memory i would go with stringBuilder.